# Replacing ASP.NET POSTBACK with jQuery form posting

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a login screen wherein I have 2 text boxes and 2 radio buttons. I have a ASP.NET button  too. When the user clicks on the button in my codebehind, in the click even of button, I have the below lines to check the user login:

```
    string emailId=txtEmailId.Text.Trim();
    string password=txtPassword.Text.Trim();
    //Code to Check user is valid...
      if(isValid)
      {
         Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
      }
      else
      {
        lblMSg.Text="InValid Login";
       }
```

This is the typical ASP.NET procedure. Now I want to avoid the post back of the page and would like to use jQuery's form posting. How can I do it ? Here I can read the ASP.NET controls value as "=txtEmailId.Text". Can I do it in jQuery form posting method? I know I can do this by passing emailid and password as query string. I don't want to use query string to do this.

Answer (score 0):

use $.Post to post back to your page http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype

Expose your method as a service method so that you can call it in the format "pagename.aspx/methodname"